# Routing error on Heroku (after logging in via Devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

For my rails 3 app I have a route setup as follows

```
namespace :user do
  root :to => "reading_schedules#index"
end
```

This is what my "rake routes" shows

```
user_root /user(.:format) {:controller=>"user/reading_schedules", :action=> "index }
```

Everything works fine on my localmachine. But as soon as I push the site up to Heroku and login I get the following error in my logs

```
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant User::ReadingSchedulesController):
```

If I navigate to the root of the site everything else works fine. But this one url doesn't work. The url it's trying to hit is `website/user` but like I said, it works fine on my localmachine.

EDIT:
Here's the rest of my routes file

```
devise_for :users, :path => 'accounts'

root :to => "home#landing"

namespace :user do
  root :to => "reading_schedules#index"
end

resources :users do
  resources :reading_schedules
  member do
    get :change_password
    post :change_password
  end
end

resources :reading_schedules do
  member do
    get :recalculate
  end
end
```

Comment: It looks like you are running into a conflict with Devise and your `user/reading_schedules` controller. Can you include your whole routes file? Also, you do have a `user/reading_schedules` controller right?

Comment: I have a `ReadingSchedules` controller but not a `user/reading_schedules`. What I don't understand is why it works on my local but not on Heroku.

Comment: curious I got exactly the same issue. Site works fine till i log in then I get errors like "No route matches {:action=>"show_seo", :controller=>"posts", :id=>#<Post id: 1...>, :title => "foo title}

Comment: it also works on my local and not with heroku. have you fixed the problem?

Comment: can you post the `eadingSchedulesController`

Answer (score 1):

I found this question first in looking for an answer to the same issue.  For any future searchers, check out this link.

For me, it was a combination of the last two answers in this post (adapted for my controllers of course.)

Also of note, this corrected the issue without having to reset the database.

[ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant User::UsersController) in heroku (but everything works in local)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530471/actioncontrollerroutingerror-uninitialized-constant-useruserscontroller-in)

Answer (score -1):

Probably not the answer you are looking for but

```
heroku rake db:reset
```

solved the problem for me. I didn't have any critical data in the 
db so it was not a problem.