# ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant User::UsersController) in heroku (but everything works in local)

Tags: heroku, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to run my app in heroku but I get this error when trying to signup or even access devise's login page:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant User::UsersController)
```

Is this a devise bug or a server setting i missed in heroku?

I am running a rails3.1 app in a cedar stack by the way and loading the index page is good, but if I try to login or sign up, it blows.

The signup form DOES show, but when I submit, that's when it blows. I checked the logs and it did POST to the controller but GETting the resulting page(when redirected I guess) blows it up.

Any help?

*EDIT*

here are my routes:

```
root :to => "home#index"

devise_for :users

namespace :user do
  root :to => "users#welcome"
end

resources :users, :only => :show
```

A heroku support person also asked about my routes but why does it happen in production only? Also I don't think there's any problem with the routes...is there?

Comment: what do your routes look like?

Comment: @Johhny Grass, i updated the question with the routes I have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
namespace :user do
  root :to => "users#welcome"
end
```

Can you remove this?

Comment: Perhaps @corroded wants that route... the other solution (using match with :as) does a similar thing, but works!

Answer (score 6):

I found the you do not need to remove the default root for when a user logs in. So replace the `namespace` call and use the following:

```
match 'users' => 'users#welcome', :as => 'user_root'
```

This way you can still have two "home" pages. It worked for me.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in

Comment: Wow, thanks! I was looking for this solution for a while!  But do you know why the namespace solution breaks in production though it seems to work in dev environment?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. Error was only reproducible in Heroku, not locally. What I realized is that while I had added the resource to routes and pushed that, all the generated scaffold was still lying locally. Once I added all the generated stuff to git and pushed, worked fine on Heroku.